# android PubSub sync failed when run the sample code from aws

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i am trying to run the sample app ( Android pub-sub app) from amazon web service but encounter "sync failed" issue and not able to run the app.

[ error display]:
   "Failed to resolve: com Affected Modules: AndroidPubSub "

```
My android studio version is 3.4  and dependencies is
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }

i changed dependencies to 3.4.0 , also cannot fix the sync failed issue.

my current gradles files under  "C:\Users\"username"\.gradle\wrapper\dists" link are 
 "gradle-4.6-all"  and " gradle-5.1.1-all "

may i know how should i fix this "sync failed" issue ?
Thank you very much.

below is the sync failed error.

C:/Android/workspace/AndroidPubSub  
build.gradle    
Failed to resolve: com
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Android/workspace/AndroidPubSub/build.gradle">AndroidPubSub</a>  
Sync Failed 5 s 228 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the answer in the AndroidPubSubWebsocket sample. You just need to change your dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
    def aws_version = "2.13.+"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:$aws_version"
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:$aws_version@aar') { transitive = true}
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:$aws_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
}
```